# Add error on Ninja Forms submit on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I'm trying to throw an error on the Ninja Forms form submit, but I want to throw a generic error, not a field-specific error.

If I have this code I get an error for the field `id=5` but I would like the error to be generic, not applied to any field.

```
add_filter('ninja_forms_submit_data', 'custom_ninja_forms_submit_data');
function custom_ninja_forms_submit_data($form_data)
{
    $form_data['errors']['fields'][5] = esc_html__('Error happened', 'custom-text-domain');

    return $form_data;
}
```

Comment: I don't have an answer how to solve your question, but I can tell you that it is virtually impossible to just display a generic error using the Ninjaforms API alone; you'll have to do some creative coding.

Comment: Yes @ZGuard I didn't see anything about that in NinjaForms API :( Thanks